# undefined method - issues calling a helper method from a partial in a mail controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've set up an ActionMailer to email and pull a partial to post the data for the user, however the helper methods are comming back as undefined - i moved them to the application helper but still the same error, I think its in the way im passing the variable to the mailer ?

I've searched for same issue online but find that theres no concise response - I fear I'm doing something basic somwewhere wrong

**Error:**

```
undefined method `tidy_address' for #<#<Class:0x007f5c90681b10>:0x007f5c90ad8ba0>
```

**My partial in order views : _enquiry_details.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">  
 <div class="col-xs-2">
    <h3><%= @customer.name %></h3>
    <hr>
    <h5><%=  tidy_address(@customer.locations.first) %></h5>
    <% @phone_number.each do |pn| %>
    <h5><%= pn.name %> : <%=pn.phone_number.phone%></h5>
    <% end %>
```

**in my user mailer.rb**

```
  def lead_received(enquiry)
    @order=enquiry
     if @order.user
      @customer=@order.user
     else
      @customer=@order.company
     end
    @locations=@customer.locations
    @phone_number=@customer.phone_maps
    mail to: "myemailaddress@domain.com", subject: "New Lead Received"

   end
```

which I call with this passing the order , think this is where im going wrong

**in order controller..**

```
if @order.save
    UserMailer.lead_received(@order).deliver_now
```

**For clarity in my mailer view  lead_received.html.erb**

```
<%= render "orders/enquiry_details" %>
```

**And finally in my locations helper**

```
module LocationsHelper

  def google_string(lat,long,size)
    case size
    when "s"
      mysize="150x150&zoom=12"
    when "m"
      mysize="350x300&zoom=14"
    when "l"
      mysize="570x300&zoom=13&scale=2"
  end
  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?"+URI.encode("markers=#{lat},#{long}&size=#{mysize}&key=AIzaSyAxRuThoVl-xziFElt3GPCESLsaye4_aGA")  
  end

  # Return a sorted neat adress block
  def tidy_address(location)
    unless location.blank?
    t_address=""
    t_address="#{location.address1}<br>" if location.address1.present?
    t_address=t_address+location.address2+"<br>" if location.address2.present?
    t_address=t_address+location.address3+"<br>" if location.address3.present?
    t_address=t_address+location.city+"<br>" if location.city.present?
    t_address=t_address+location.postcode if location.postcode.present?
    # t_address=t_address+"("+location.id.to_s+")"
    #t_address=t_address+"<br><a href=''>Directions to here</a>"
    t_address.html_safe
  else
    t_address="<link_to 'Add an address' '#'>".html_safe
  end
end
```

end

Comment: check whether you defined `tidy_address` in private block?

Comment: `gravatar_for` isn't error for application helper. where are you using `gravatar_for`?

Comment: Its called from user controller and it also throws the same error, i commented it out to simplify the question and testing

Comment: Anand - Altered to include full helper content so no its public.

Comment: Can you add the code where you call `gravatar_for` method?

Comment: Corrections applied - there was 2 calls causing the same issue, one to gravatar_for() in the user helper one too  tidy_address in the locations helper - its simpler and easier to address only one of them as the same issue will solve both

Comment: You need to include the helper see my answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the helper in the mailer code to use inside mailer.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: "" # default from email
  helper LocationsHelper
  helper UserHelper      

  def lead_received(enquiry)
    @order=enquiry

    if @order.user
      @customer=@order.user
    else
      @customer=@order.company
    end

    @locations=@customer.locations
    @phone_number=@customer.phone_maps
    mail to: "myemailaddress@domain.com", subject: "New Lead Received"
  end
end
```